# Python 3.5 (32 Bit) in Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, python3

I'm having trouble solving this even though I searched a lot. I have installed python 3.5 (32 bit) on my computer that runs 64 bit Windows 7.

I can use normal functions of python but when I try to use the function `pip install numpy`, it always gives me the following error: `[Errno 13] Permission Denied`.

I always log in using an administrator user account so why does it say permission denied?

I also tried to install the Python 3.5 (64 Bit) but same error occured.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

An administrator account is not the same as admin priviledges.

You can install `numpy` from `cmd` with admin priviledges. On desktop press `ctrl + x` and then `a` to select admin command prompt. From there run `pip install numpy`.

Alternatively, your python installation has been installed with admin-only write permissions. Go to the installation folder in explorer and then go to properties for the folder. There enable 'all permissions' for your user in security tab and the run `pip install numpy` as normal user.

Comment: i made what you said but it seems it still not working

Comment: Permission Denied again? even with admin cmd prompt?

Comment: Yup, but i access cmd from windows then type cmd -> right click -> run as administrator